# Explanation of Josh Smith Article

Tags: c#, mvvm, icommand

Many of you are familiar with Josh Smith.  He does a brilliant job of explaining things, but one particular statement he makes in the article:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx

has me confused...

Regarding the `ICommand` and `RelayCommand` class he mentions:

> One possible implementation pattern is to create a private nested class within the ViewModel class, so that the command has access to private members of its containing ViewModel and does not pollute the namespace.

Maybe because I'm new to this I'm having a hard time visualizing what he is saying.  Could someone send me some pseudo code to explain this?  I think seeing the code would help me grasp the concept.

Comment: How do I accept?  I don't see any buttons, etc.?

Comment: Click on your username to view your profile.  Go to your previously asked questions.  In each of those questions click the checkmark below the "up-vote" tool for the best answer to your question.

Comment: Ok, thanks.  I've gone through my questions and accepted the best answer.  Can anyone help me with this question?

Comment: This would be a better question if you took a stab at the pseudo code yourself so we could see where your head's at. That exercise alone may be enough to give you that "aha!" moment.

Comment: @Jeff - Not the "best" answer. Only accept answers that actually helped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class Foo
{
   private static int f;

   private class Bar  // nested class
   {
       void B() 
       { 
          int b = f;  // access to private member of containing class
       }
   }
}
```

But do note the article continues *without* using this.